# Calculate limit: Make a stopping time $T$ bounded $T\land n$ and take the limit $n \to \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Say we have a martingale $X$ and a stopping time $T$.

Instead of directly studying the stopped process $X_T$, many proofs employ a trick,
namely, one considers the bounded stopping time $T\land n$ and instead studies $X_{T\land n}$ and then letting $n \to \infty$ at some point.

I'm trying to prove that
$$ \lim_n X_{T \land n} = X_T \mathbf{1}_{\{T < \infty\}}.$$

Intuitively it makes sense but I'm stuck trying to prove it.

**Edit Update**: Like saz noted in the comments below the above limit is not true in general if $P(T = \infty) > 0$.

I consider this solved as it cleared up my misunderstanding.

Comment: If $\mathbb{P}(T=\infty)>0$ then this does, in general, not hold true. You will need to multiply the left-hand side with $1_{\{T<\infty\}}$ ...

Comment: Thank you @saz ! Your comment made me realize I had made an erroneous assumption earlier in a proof I was working on.

Comment: So.. did this solve/answer your question? You might want to notice that if $T(\omega)<\infty$ then $T(\omega) \wedge n = T(\omega)$ for $n \geq N(\omega)$ sufficiently large, and therefore the convergence is really not difficult to show.

Comment: Yes, I consider it solved. As you pointed out it's not true in general. So no wonder I struggled to prove my false claim. If we add the factor $\mathbf{1}_{\{T < \infty\}}$ to the left-hand side it becomes much easier.